# Where to save temp files for Windows Azure website, and access them from worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a website where users upload some images and then do some processes on these images, then the user will download these images, and I have a Windows app which deletes these images based on a schedule, and deletes images which are older than 1 hour, which means the user can access the uploaded images for just one hour.

Currently I have the website and the Windows app working on the same dedicated server, and I want to move to Azure.

My question is:
Where to save these images, which I will need to keep for just one hour, and be able to access these images from a worker role to delete them based on a schedule?

I will put the website on Windows Azure Websites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer would really depend on where the web app is running, and I'm thinking this question may end up getting closed due to the broad nature of it. But... In general, you should consider using blob storage for your images. This way, *any* compute instance in Azure can access it, whether in Virtual machines, web/worker role instances, or Web Site instances.

As for 1-hour access, you can easily set up Shared Access Signatures which expire in an hour. You can then have these links embedded in your html output, and have your users direct-access the images. As for deleting, I'm sure there are lots of techniques. One such technique is to place a "delete blob" message, for a specific blob, on an Azure queue, with an initial invisibility of 1-hour. Then you can have a background task reading from the queue and deleting old blobs.